# Getting json data from rails method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I think i am missing something silly here , but cannot figure out and its been more than an hour trying. So without wasting time ..

I want to fetch `index` action in `Users` controller using **json**. 
 For example `localhost:3000/users.json` right now gives me data ..

`[{"id":17,"url":"http://localhost:3000/users/17.json"},{"id":16,"url":"http://localhost:3000/users/16.json"}]`

But i have other attributes in **User** table like `first_name` and `last_name` etc.. which i would like to use from json.

How should i modify my existing method to get the required details.

```
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
   @users = User.all
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, :first_name, :last_name)
    end
```

Comment: Please show us the view for your `index` action. It's likely that you've not added extra parameters there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to open `app/views/users/index.jbuilder` and add the attributes you want there.

Comment: gotit ..simple..i dint even realize that exists a file called index.json.jbuilder till now

Answer (score 3):

change your index method to :

```
def index
 @users = User.all
 render :json => @users
end
```

this will show the json on `localhost:3000/users`

alternatively if you want it explicitly on `localhost:3000/users.json`

use `respond_to` like below:

```
def index 
  @users = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render :json => @users}
  end
end
```